# Facebook "Canvas URL" field missing

Tags: facebook, canvas

On Facebook developers under app administration, App on Facebook, there are suppose to be two fields. Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL. Well, today they are gone.

Were there some changes on Facebook or it's a bug?

[image: App on Facebook Tab]

**Edit:**
Seems that they fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one has to enable Unity integration now to get these input fields to show.

Edit: It’s a bug, they are working on a fix.

Comment: "You have enabled a App on Facebook with a plugin canvas integration for your app, but have not specified a Unity Binary URL."  What to do now?

Comment: I'm going to have a beer and retry tomorrow.

Comment: Great:(. Now login through oauth inside canvas doesn't work. Had to move app outside canvas to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent the bug by enabling unity integration, change your canvas url, open web inspector in chrome and manually set disabled's value property to true and enabled to false.

The screenshot shows the correct changes for both, "Disabled" and "Enabled".

Upon save, your new URL is registered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

- Turn on unity integration
- Insert your urls
- Turn off unity integration
- Save!

No errors, no inspector.