# Why the "Secure Canvas URL" in my facebook app is hidden? (has the hidden_elem class name)

Tags: facebook

Why the "Secure Canvas URL" in my facebook app settings is hidden? 
(has the hidden_elem class name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook "Canvas URL" field missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684089/facebook-canvas-url-field-missing)

Comment: It's hidden because Facebook doesn't really like people developing on their platform :/